# Error creating new project in Winginx (Hm stops working) - Windows 8.1 64-bit

Tags: winginx

I installed Winginx in Windows 8.1 64-bit, the server operates normally, but can not create a new project:

When i try to create a new project, after entering all the information and click create, i get a Windows message that Hm stopped working.

Has anyone had this problem?

I made a screencast of what's happening.

http://www.screencast.com/users/Jplto/folders/Default/media/be4bf57c-8ae3-4df0-b86c-0d76d10c87c2

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem couple of minutes ago - then debugged it right away. It seems to me that your hosts file is set to read only (RO), so Winginx cannot alter it.

The solution could be either giving proper rights to `hm` (hosts manager, i presume), or uncheck the RO property of the hosts file -- it is commonly found under `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\`

Take care

EDIT:

I also found out that NET HTTP services interfere with some WinGinx services. I think it *might* be the issue, too. This works for me (run cmd as admin): `NET STOP HTTP`